# Flutter Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 14

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos, dart, cocoapods

I use flutter and it was working fine without any problem and suddenly this came out of nowhere "Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 14." and it happened to my friend too who work on the same project
Note we are using Mac

I tried flutter clean and run it again
pod update and also I delete the iOS folder and I put back my runner folder ...
I even start all over new Project and firebase

Comment: Have you tried running the project from Xcode? Sometimes that will clear up such issues.

Comment: You might have a dependency which is not compatible with the newest version of Flutter — I recently ran into this issue with the package modal_bottom_sheet

Comment: how to know which package is not compatible with the newest version

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing a new flutter project and paste all the lab folder files one by one on it
Deleted the new iOS folder and also paste my old one instead

then in the terminal
flutter pub cache repair
flutter update

and it worked